# Apply lambda to an object

Tags: ruby, lambda, metaprogramming

Let say I have a variable and lambda defined somewhere

```
phone = "1(234)567-89-01"
lambda = -> { gsub(/[^0-9]/, '') }
```

How can I apply lambda to the phone to get `12345678901`?

P.S. I know I can go with the following approach:

```
lambda = -> (arg) { arg.gsub(/[^0-9]/, '') }
lambda.call(phone)
#=> "12345678901"
```

But I want to be laconic.

Comment: `-> (arg) { arg }` is preferable

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use [BasicObject#`instance_exec`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.2/BasicObject.html#method-i-instance_exec):

```
phone.instance_exec &lambda
#=> "12345678901"
```

Comment: good stuff @AndreyDeineko,  and the nice thing about this is that it wont change state of the original  `phone`  ( after exec, phone var it's still `"1(234)567-89-01"` ) ... so in order to work with new value: `new_phone = phone.instance_exec(&lambda)`